# Counting unique values when other criteria must also be met

Tags: google-sheets, unique, formula, google-query-language

I'm having difficultly with Google Sheets counting unique rows, where other criteria in the formula must also be met.

I've created a simple Google Sheet to highlight the problem I need solving.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P0sHIUN12Wpbr6vKJAwsPluj-T2H-NrPpQ1_WWV7lvI/edit?usp=sharing

I need the formula in cell C5 to only count unique values in row G, where the criteria is met in rows F & H (the SP is “DG” and the likelihood is “Booked”). I cannot work out how to make this only count unique values. The formula I currently have only counts any cells that are not blank in row G, it does not look for unique values but needs to.

The working formula should give the following answers:

```
C3 = <>  C5 should equal 3
C3 = 1  C5 should equal 1
C3 = 2  C5 should equal 2
C3 = 3  C5 should equal 1
```

Please can someone help?

EDIT
The formulas I've already tried won't make sense with the example in the link but to show what I have attempted

```
=COUNTIF(UNIQUE(QUERY(AA:AM,"Select AC where AA = 'DG' and AL = 'Booked' and AM = '" & I2 & "'")),"<>")
```

It returned a 1 regardless of how many it should have returned.

Comment: The formulas tried won't make sense with the example in the link but this has been tried =COUNTIF(UNIQUE(QUERY(AA:AM,"Select AC where AA = 'DG' and AL = 'Booked' and AM = '" & I2 & "'")),"<>")  It returned 1 regardless of how many it should have returned. I've also tried various variations of this too that didn't work and now asking here with an example sheet

Comment: Why are you posting effort in comments? Edit your question so that useful and [necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) information is present.

Comment: I was answering your question. I think it's clear I'm not very experienced either with Google Sheets or using this site. I have tried for weeks to get this to work (while actually doing my day to day job) and at the point of giving up, even though I know it can be done!

Comment: i would greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=COUNTUNIQUE(QUERY(F2:I21,"Select G where F='DG' and H='Booked' "&IF(ISBLANK(C3),,"and I="&C3&"")))
```

- QUERY to get G  column subject to conditions
- COUNTUNIQUE to count unique G Rows

Comment: Hello, this appears to be working perfectly if a particular week is entered in the cell C3. With the actual sheet we use, we had been using <> in C3 to show the results of all weeks. With your formula having <> in C3 returns 1, when it should in fact return 3. Is there a way to adapt the formula to do this? Thank you so much though as this is as close as we've come to having it working.

Comment: @theme I've used ISBLANK()... If you clear C3, You'll get 3. Otherwise, change the isblank condition ....

Comment: You're absolutely right, thank you so much. You have no idea how pleased I am that this is working. Thanks!

Comment: Hello @I'-'I, thanks again for your help. Upon implementing the formula to our sheet we found a slight issue that you can hopefully help with.
Sometimes Column I will be blank, there will be no booking week and the formula/query should not count these. Leaving C3 blank works perfectly in running the query on all data, we just need it to ignore the rows where I is empty.

Comment: With the original formula we used (that didn’t only count uniques) we solved it by putting a `‘<>’` in C3.
`=COUNTIFS(G:G, "<>", H:H,"Booked",F:F,"DG",I:I,C3)`

With your formula below can we add a similar thing like and I=<> to only pull data from rows not blank.
`=COUNTUNIQUE(QUERY(F2:I21,"Select G where F='DG' and H='Booked' and I=<> "&IF(ISBLANK(C3),,"and I="&C3&"")))`

Comment: @theme change the `ISBLANK()` condition inside the `IF`. If that doesn't work, Potray  your new problem in the sheet and edit your question with the followup problem. Desired output and actual output.